# Use VueJS events inside blade template

Tags: javascript, events, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have an ajax view which is getting appended to my vue container and I try to figure out if I could add some vue events in my blade template and letting vue to listen to events

for example in blade

```
<td v-on:click="methodToCall(tdData)"></td>
```

and in vue

```
  methods: {

         methodToCall(data) {

     }
 }
```

hole scenario

I have an ajax view which is getting appended to my vue container and I try to figure out if I could add some vue events in my blade template and letting vue to listen to events

for example in blade

```
<td v-on:click="methodToCall(tdData)"></td>
```

and in vue

```
  methods: {

         methodToCall(data) {

     }
 }
```

the hole scenario

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="stats"></div>
        <span class="loading"></span>
    </div>
</template>


<script>

    export default {

        props: ['user'],

        created() {            
           this.fetchData(this.user);            
        },

        methods: {

            fetchData(user) {
                axios.get('/api/v1/user/' + user, {
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                }).then(response => {
                    this.data = response.data.view;
                    $('#stats').append(this.data);
                    $('#supplyUser').select2();

                }).catch(error => {

                });
            },
            methodForBladeAction() {} 

        },



        data() {
            return {
                allProjects: {},
                year: null,
                data: {},
                listing: []
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

a part of my blade is getting generated by a function

```
 $td .= '<td title="'. $employeeList .'" '
                    . 'class=" leer'. $isSupplied . $offDay .'"'
                    . 'v-on:click="method()"'
                    . 'data-user     = "'. $employee .'" '
                    . 'data-week     = "'.$flowDate->format('W').'" '
                    . 'data-year-day = "'.$flowDate->format('W').'" '
                    . 'data-date     = "'. $current->format('Y-m-d') .'" '
                    . 'data-hour     = "'. $hour_start .'"><div>'. $workspace . '</div></td>';
```

than I include in my blade like

```
{!! $service->hoursOnDays($supply, $employee, $workspaces, $dates, $data, $holidays) !!}
```

Comment: Have you tried that? There isn't any issue using vue in blade, but what is `tdData`? Is that in a `v-for`? Could you add a little more code to make it clearer where your problem lies, plus any errors?

Comment: I tried but I get undefined function on methodToCall()

Comment: Something else is happening, could you add more of your blade template and your vue instance?

Comment: So you want to access a method from the blade template that is inside a child component, is that correct?

Comment: yes that would be the idea